# JavaScript addition and subtraction doesn't work but multiplication and division works

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 2000000000000000000;
a = a - 1; //Doesn't work
a = a + 1; //Doesn't work
```

But

```
a = a * 10; //Works
a = a / 10; //Works
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?

You can try this example in browser console.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Too long int: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5 Other answer on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t#307200

Comment: @OliCharlesworth try it.

Comment: @Jeevan: Not a good response.  It would take you two seconds to add the relevant output/error description to your question, thus making it self-contained.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Sorry. Doesn't work means addition is not performed, ie if we do 2 + 1 , We should get 3 as the result. It gives me 2 as the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running into the limits of JavaScript integer calculus.

The largest integer number, JavaScript can use with full precision is **9007199254740992**.

Your number is larger and thus will be internally represented as a `double`. As a consequence you run into all the problems associated with floating point calculus, which you see here.

Comment: @Jeevan See, e.g., [Wikipedia on floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).